# Load the JSON into the container

Tags: javascript, json, html

```
  $(".btn-primary").click(function(){ 
  success(jsonObj); 
  });
```

In the [JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/WsnDP/13/) how do I reload only the container. everytime I change the JSON I need to RUN the code, how can I do it with the button

Comment: You mean like push notifications? Like the server letting the client know of a change? That's pretty complicated, but it certainly can be done with websockets. what about polling the JSON every X seconds?

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean the JSON _string_ right?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're asking, there's nothing wrong with your code that I can see. The issue is that what you're trying to do is outside the scope of what JSFiddle can do. When you change things in js fiddle, it doesn't dynamically change your javascript as well, you have to reload the page for it to reload your javascript.

Comment: Jeff You got me correctly. but the problem is in my demo http://helloworld.site44.com/ I face the same problem.

Comment: You never change the value of `jsonObj`, so clicking the button will always load the same value. It looks like you want to put the `$.getJSON` call into the click event handler, i.e. `$(".btn-primary").click(function(){  $.getJSON("...", success); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was simple. 
It was a cache problem.
Just need to add

```
      $ajaxSetup({cache: false}); //in the call back function
```

and

```
      $ajaxSetup({cache: true});
```